# erro ao emular projeto com firebase flutter version 1.22.2

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[18.0.2].
> Required by:
> project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:18.0.2
> project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:18.0.2
> project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk:18.0.2
> project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:18.0.2 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:18.0.2
> project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:18.0.2 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.2
> > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-base/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-base/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-base/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You have bintray as a repository in your Gradle configuration. Bintray has been sunset for years... Remove that and maybe replace with just `mavenCentral()` and that should fix the problem.